# generate random numbers (no member generate exist error)

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I'm trying to create an object that is supposed to implement some methods for my roulette program, but when compiling I got error that no member generate exist in std::random_device

here is a class example:

```
#include <random>
class Engine
{
public:
    Engine();

    int spin();
private:
    std::mt19937 m_generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> m_distribution;
    std::random_device m_seed;
};


Engine::Engine() :
    m_generator(m_seed),
    m_distribution(0, 36)
{
}

int Engine::spin()
{
    return m_distribution(m_generator);
}
```

// now let's try it out

```
Engine eng;

for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    eng.spin();
```

what am I doing wrong?

the above code opens a std header with code that is not easy to understand

Comment: Fyi, `m_seed` needs construction *first*. Move it to the head of your member var decl list in-class, as that is the order of initialization. And to invoke its functional member `operator ()` you need `m_generator (m_seed())`, not  `m_generator(m_seed)`.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/EA4AYU

Comment: @WhozCraig AAHAaaaaa :D tnx, juanchipanza, thank you for this that helps

Comment: @TemplateRex OK, I added something.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The engine `std::mt19937` requires a seed in its constructor. You are passing it an `std::random_device`. It looks like you intended to do something like

```
Engine::Engine() : m_generator(m_seed()), m_distribution(0, 36) {}
                                     ^^
```

You should also make sure `m_seed` has been initialized before it is used. This will require declaring it before `m_generator`:

```
private:
    std::random_device m_seed;
    std::mt19937 m_generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> m_distribution;
```

although I suspect you don't really need that member, and you can say

```
Engine::Engine() : m_generator(std::random_device()()), 
                   m_distribution(0, 36) {}
```

See this [**live example**](http://ideone.com/EA4AYU).